# Why is it not possible to load a UIViewController from a nib into Swift Playground?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, nib, swift-playground

1. Create a new playground
2. Create an UI file (xib) and add it to the "Resources" folder in playground
3. In the xib, drag a UIViewController into the canvas. By default it will have a UIView attached to it. Leave it there.
4. In the terminal, compile the xib into a nib (using `ibtool --compile out.nib in.xib`). Now there's a nib file that you can use.

Finally in Playground, load the VC from the nib and assign it to playground's live view:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyVC: UIViewController {

}

let vc = MyVC(nibName: "vc", bundle: nil)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Doesn't matter how I slice it, keep getting "*loaded the "vc" nib but the view outlet was not set*" error.

I've exhausted all my search results and book reading on this issue in vain. Maybe this is not possible?

I can load a UIView from a nib just fine. I can also create a view controller class in playground and in its `loadView` method, I can load a UIView from a nib and assign it to the VC's `view`. But I can't seem to just load the view controller itself from a nib...?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to load it as a UINib and instantiate the view controller from there as the first object in the returned array:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "vc", bundle: nil)
let nibArray = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)
let vc = nibArray.first as! UIViewController
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```